# Jackcess from R using rJava in OSX

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava, jackcess

I tried all the suggestions in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053273/use-jackcess-from-r-using-rjava) and still get the last error

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(force.init = T)
.jaddClassPath(dir('~/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/',full.names = TRUE)))
mol.db <- "~/Downloads/SEPULVEDA_MOLECULAR.accdb"
jfile = .jnew('java/io/File',mol.db)
dbbo <- .jnew("com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/DatabaseBuilder")
dbbo <- .jcall(dbbo,"Lcom/healthmarketscience/jackcess/DatabaseBuilder;","setFile",jfile)
db <- .jcall(dbbo,"Lcom/healthmarketscience/jackcess/Database;","open",evalArray = FALSE,evalString = FALSE) # fails!!!!


Error in .jcall(dbbo, "Lcom/healthmarketscience/jackcess/Database;", "open", : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Here is the result of .jclassPath()

"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/library/rJava/java"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/commons-codec-1.10"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/commons-lang-2.6"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/commons-logging-1.1.3"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/jackcess-2.1.6.jar"    "/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/log4j-1.2.7.jar" 
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/poi-3.9"
"/Users/JS/Dropbox/R_packages/JavaJS/ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar"

sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053273/use-jackcess-from-r-using-rjava) en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053273/use-jackcess-from-r-using-rjava) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053273/use-jackcess-from-r-using-rjava) rJava_0.9-8       tibble_1.2        datapasta_1.0.0   rlist_0.4.6.1     pipeR_0.6.1.3     janitor_0.2.1     data.table_1.10.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053273/use-jackcess-from-r-using-rjava) magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 tools_3.3.2    DBI_0.5-1      dplyr_0.5.0    Rcpp_0.12.8

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you notice the edit in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32053273/2144390) where they said "well I found the answer to this step, I just needed a semicolon (;) at the end of class definition string"?

Comment: @gord-thompson I did! Edited the question to include the code.